# Why create ruby libs to manage simple config files in chef ?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am new to chef just playing around with community cookbooks. I have seen that every cookbook have a lib,s and templates to manage simple Linux config files. We pass different parameters through these ruby lib,s.

My question is what if i install my desired package with "package" resource and then move all of it,s config files "cookbook_file" resource. e.g

```
package 'nrpe' do
  action :install
end

cookbook_file "/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg" do
  source "entry-nrpe.cfg"
  mode "0644"
end
```

Is it okay to use chef like this ?

Answer (score 2):

Because everyone has a slightly different idea of "normal" when it comes to server operations. For your own cookbooks, absolutely just do things like that (well, maybe use a template instead of a static file but same general idea). For cookbooks built specifically to be shared, community code we need to make sure they are flexible enough to account for at least a large proportion of the use cases in the community. There are still several patterns in use, but mostly we've all settled on very resource-heavy instead of recipe-heavy code for these "library style" cookbooks.

Overall, not something you need to worry about as a user, mostly a pattern used by a few specific authors for a specific purpose :)

Comment: Thanks, One question though, what do you mean by "resource-heavy instead of recipe-heavy" ?